# Conditions on domain of integration

Tags: integration, notation

Let $A = [0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $r\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $v\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$.

What is the most clear and standard notation for the integral $\int\limits_D r\,\mathrm{d}V $, where $D = \{ (x,y,z) | (x,y,z) \in A, r(x,y,z) > r_0,v(x,y,z)<v_0\}$, and $r_0$ and $v_0$ are constants?

Comment: This seems fairly reasonable, although many would write $D=\{(x,y,z)\in A|r(x,z,y)>r_0,v(x,y,z)<v_0\}$.  Is $r$ meant to have an unusual order of its arguments?  If you want to change $r_0$ or $v_0$, you could include them in the notation for $D$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelBurr. I corrected the order of the arguments of r. Could you please explain the last sentence of your comment?

Comment: If you want to allow $r_0$ or $v_0$ to vary, you could write $D(r_0,v_0)$ or $D_{r_0,v_0}$ to indicate the dependence on $r_0$ and $v_0$.

Comment: Now I see, thanks!